# .attr not working - JQuery

Tags: jquery

For some reason the value inside the .attr method below is not firing. I used the same method for other buttons and they are working fine. The buttons below are created using Javascript so I'm not sure if that's why the .attr method isn't working. I also tried using .data but that didn't seem to work either. Thanks!

```
$("#video-navbar button").data('data-ga-event', '{"category":"see-whats-new", "action":"video", "label":"nav"}');
```

Comment: You are not using `attr`? You probably mean to use `$("#video-navbar button").data('ga-event','{...}'`) without the `data-`

Answer (score 1):

when using `data()` you don't need `data-` prefix

```
$("#video-navbar button")
.data('ga-event', '...');
```

you will need it using `attr()`

```
$("#video-navbar button")
    .attr('data-ga-event', '...');
```